# HTTP request with RESTful URL and .htm URL

Tags: spring-mvc, restful-url

URL with `*.htm` works fine. But I encounter a problem is when I try to access RESTful URL without `*.htm`, then the server gives me `404` error. Well I can solve the problem by replacing `*.htm` with `/`. If I do that then I break my webpages. So the question is how do I go about supporting `RESTful` and regular `HTTP request` through the same Spring Controller? What needs to be configured in `Web.xml`? I tried something like `/rest/*` but that does not seems to be working either.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatch</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatch</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Tried

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatch</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Tested with configuration 'Type - I'**

Works when URL is set to end with `.htm` `http://localhost:8080/controllerName/my/123/url/value.htm`

Web.xml mapping

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatch</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatch</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Controller Mapping

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/my/{number}/url/{somevalue}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/xml")
```

**Test with configuration 'Type - II'**

No other combination seems to work when URL does not contain `.htm`

Comment: There is no need keep the `.htm` extension at all, especially not for RESTful API. Google for "URL Rewrite" to see how you can configure the webserver of your choice to use URL rewrites. This will make it possible use any url format

Comment: Are you sure /rest/* didn't work? How did your controller mapping look like when you used it and what URLs you were testing it with?

Comment: When I tried with `/rest/*` the `URL` still had to end with `.htm` otherwise it did not work. In short `/rest/my/123/url/9990` did not work but `/rest/my/123/url/9990.htm` worked.

Comment: How did the mapping in the controller look like? Was it @RequestMapping(value = "/rest/my/123/url/{id}") or @RequestMapping(value = "/my/123/url/{id}")? The 2nd one should work.

Comment: Mapping in controller looks like `@RequestMapping(value = "/my/{number}/url/{somevalue}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/xml")`. Have your tried? Or do you have an example to share? Using Spring 3.2.4.

Comment: App I'm working on works correctly with the configuration you mentioned in last comment, I'll copy/paste an example to the answer. In the mean time, when you're making requests, is the Accept header set to "application/xml"?

Comment: Request - `Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8` Response - `Content-Type:application/xml`. Also will update my question in short while to reflect what all I have tried.

Answer (score 0):

This may be late, but it may be an issue with the DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping in Spring.  It will, by default I believe, automatically handle extentions, but that can be turned off.  Also, your Servlet definition in your web.xml should be set to accept URLs ending in '*'.